# In Dockerfile for Azure Functions isolated .NET 7, why are two versions of runtime (6.0) and SDK (7.0) used?

Tags: docker, .net-core

In Visual Studio (version 17.4.3), creating a **.NET 7.0 Functions App with Isolated worker process** and **Docker enabled** gives me below `Dockerfile` template.

For what reason are two different versions of the runtime (6.0) and the SDK (7.0) used?

Isolated worker process obviously [supports .NET 7.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide#supported-versions).

```dockerfile
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated:4-dotnet-isolated7.0 AS base
WORKDIR /home/site/wwwroot
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:6.0 as runtime6.0
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
# Copy .NET Core 6.0 runtime from the 6.0 image
COPY --from=runtime6.0 /usr/share/dotnet/host /usr/share/dotnet/host
COPY --from=runtime6.0 /usr/share/dotnet/shared /usr/share/dotnet/shared
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["FunctionApp1/FunctionApp1.csproj", "FunctionApp1/"]
RUN dotnet restore "FunctionApp1/FunctionApp1.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/FunctionApp1"
RUN dotnet build "FunctionApp1.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "FunctionApp1.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /home/site/wwwroot
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot \
    AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true
```

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me, if your `.csproj` only contains `net7.0` for `<TargetFramework>` and `v4` for `<AzureFunctionsVersion>`

Comment: Yes, but what makes hesitant of removing the `COPY` lines, is the deliberate way the have been added (with a comment "Copy .NET Core 6.0 runtime...").

Answer (score 0):

Given that .NET SDK image [contains the following](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-sdk/):

- .NET CLI
- .NET runtime
- ASP.NET Core

I don't think that part is necessary at all. Otherwise, feel free to change the version to `runtime:7.0`